# How to search for special characters in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I got the requirements that I have to search for special characters like the names who are having single quotes in their names `c'te`

ex:

```
select * from names where name like 'c'test%'
```

For this I got the solution like

```
select * from names where name like '%''%'
```

The above answer is useful to search  who are having single quotes in their names but my requirement is how do i search the name directly  like

```
select * from names where name like 'c'test%'
```

because from application side they will search for the lable last name d'tech

Please note that we should not pass any extra quotes while searching the names

Help on this with example will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just need to double them up (I don't know what "should not pass any extra quotes" means but this is how you do it):

```
select column1,column2 -- don't use *
from dbo.names -- always use schema prefix
where name like 'c''test%'; -- terminate with semi-colon
```

However if you use properly parameterized statements you shouldn't need to worry about it. You only need to worry about escaping single quotes if you are building your query dynamically, which you shouldn't be doing because you lose strong typing and open yourself up to SQL injection. Quick example:

```cs
string sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE @Name;";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", "c'test"));
  ...
}
```